# asp.net mvc 3 calling a controller's action using either jquery or ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem calling an action using javascript. So, I calculate a distance between two latitudes and longitudes. Now, If that distance is greater than 100 miles I want to call "distant" action in home controller that would return different view, but if it's less I would like to stay with index action. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What are you returning?  Partial view?  JSON?

Comment: Partial view. I added all the javascript in Home/index view is it the right place to do it?

Comment: Ideally you'd move the javascript into a separate file and keep your view as clean as possible.

Comment: if(distance > 100){
$.ajax({ url: "Home/Distant" })
}
doesn't do anything, I still keep getting index view. I am sure that distance is greater than 100 though.

Comment: are you wiring up your `success` and `error` handlers?

Comment: I am completely new to this stuff. I need to play around with it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you just do something like:

```
if (distance > 100) {
  $.ajax({url: 'distantURL', ...});
} else {
  $.ajax({url: 'closeURL", ...});
}
```

Without additional information, it's tough to give a more detailed and/or accurate answer.

**EDIT**: Here's a nice [walk-through tutorial](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingJQueryAjaxToLoadAPartialViewInASPNETMVC2AndThenRetrieveTheInputOnTheServerAgain.aspx) of loading a partial view via jQuery's `$.ajax()` function, which sounds like what you want to do.